# Is it possible to do a zip operation in apache beam on two PCollections?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a `PCollection[str]` and I want to generate random pairs.

Coming from Apache Spark, my strategy was to:

1. copy the original PCollection
2. randomly shuffle it
3. zip it with the original PCollection

However I can't seem to find a way to zip 2 PCollections...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is interesting and a not very common use case because, as @chamikara says, there is no order guarantee in Dataflow. However, I thought about implementing a solution where you shuffle the input PCollection and then pair consecutive elements based on [state](https://beam.apache.org/blog/2017/02/13/stateful-processing.html) . I have found some caveats in the way but I thought it might be worth sharing anyway.

First, I have used the Python SDK but the Dataflow Runner does not support stateful DoFn's yet. It works with the Direct Runner but: 1) it is not scalable and 2) it's difficult to shuffle the records without multi-threading. Of course, an easy solution for the latter is to feed an already shuffled PCollection to the pipeline (we can use a different job to pre-process the data). Otherwise, we can adapt this example to the Java SDK.

For now, I decided to try to shuffle and pair it with a single pipeline. I don't really know if this helps or makes things more complicated but code can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/gxercavins/68541deedbe8acdaeb890b80e4b7fbf9).

Briefly, the stateful DoFn looks at the buffer and if it is empty it puts in the current element. Otherwise, it pops out the previous element from the buffer and outputs a tuple of (previous_element, current_element):

```py
class PairRecordsFn(beam.DoFn):
  """Pairs two consecutive elements after shuffle"""
  BUFFER = BagStateSpec('buffer', PickleCoder())
  def process(self, element, buffer=beam.DoFn.StateParam(BUFFER)):
    try:
      previous_element = list(buffer.read())[0]
    except:
      previous_element = []
    unused_key, value = element

    if previous_element:
      yield (previous_element, value)
      buffer.clear()
    else:
      buffer.add(value)
```

The pipeline adds keys to the input elements as required to use a stateful DoFn. Here there will be a trade-off because you can potentially assign the same key to all elements with `beam.Map(lambda x: (1, x))`. This would not parallelize well but it's not a problem as we are using the Direct Runner anyway (keep it in mind if using the Java SDK). However, it will not shuffle the records. If, instead, we shuffle to a large amount of keys we'll get a larger number of "orphaned" elements that can't be paired (as state is preserved per key and we assign them randomly we can have an odd number of records per key):

```py
pairs = (p
  | 'Create Events' >> beam.Create(data)
  | 'Add Keys' >> beam.Map(lambda x: (randint(1,4), x))
  | 'Pair Records' >> beam.ParDo(PairRecordsFn())
  | 'Check Results' >> beam.ParDo(LogFn()))
```

In my case I got something like:

```py
INFO:root:('one', 'three')
INFO:root:('two', 'five')
INFO:root:('zero', 'six')
INFO:root:('four', 'seven')
INFO:root:('ten', 'twelve')
INFO:root:('nine', 'thirteen')
INFO:root:('eight', 'fourteen')
INFO:root:('eleven', 'sixteen')
...
```

EDIT: I thought of another way to do so using the `Sample.FixedSizeGlobally` combiner. The good thing is that it shuffles the data better but you need to know the number of elements a priori (otherwise we'd need an initial pass on the data) and it seems to return all elements together. Briefly, I initialize the same PCollection twice but apply different shuffle orders and assign indexes in a stateful DoFn. This will guarantee that indexes are unique across elements in the same PCollection (even if no order is guaranteed). In my case, both PCollections will have exactly one record for each key in the range [0, 31]. A CoGroupByKey transform will join both PCollections on the same index thus having random pairs of elements:

```py
pc1 = (p
  | 'Create Events 1' >> beam.Create(data)
  | 'Sample 1' >> combine.Sample.FixedSizeGlobally(NUM_ELEMENTS)
  | 'Split Sample 1' >> beam.ParDo(SplitFn())
  | 'Add Dummy Key 1' >> beam.Map(lambda x: (1, x))
  | 'Assign Index 1' >> beam.ParDo(IndexAssigningStatefulDoFn()))

pc2 = (p
  | 'Create Events 2' >> beam.Create(data)
  | 'Sample 2' >> combine.Sample.FixedSizeGlobally(NUM_ELEMENTS)
  | 'Split Sample 2' >> beam.ParDo(SplitFn())
  | 'Add Dummy Key 2' >> beam.Map(lambda x: (2, x))
  | 'Assign Index 2' >> beam.ParDo(IndexAssigningStatefulDoFn()))

zipped = ((pc1, pc2)
           | 'Zip Shuffled PCollections' >> beam.CoGroupByKey()
           | 'Drop Index' >> beam.Map(lambda (x, y):y)
           | 'Check Results' >> beam.ParDo(LogFn()))
```

Full code [here](https://gist.github.com/gxercavins/5e90adc86e4a6e40ee91182437fb033d)

Results:

```py
INFO:root:(['ten'], ['nineteen'])
INFO:root:(['twenty-three'], ['seven'])
INFO:root:(['twenty-five'], ['twenty'])
INFO:root:(['twelve'], ['twenty-one'])
INFO:root:(['twenty-six'], ['twenty-five'])
INFO:root:(['zero'], ['twenty-three'])
...
```

Answer (score 1):

How about applying a [ParDo](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#pardo) transform to both PCollections that attach keys to elements and running the two PCollections through a [CoGroupByKey](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#cogroupbykey) transform ?

Please note that Beam does not guarantee order of elements in a PCollection so output elements might get reordered after any step but seems like this should be OK for your use-case since you just need some random order.